# Android camera removing fragment in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I have one parent activity, In which replacing the fragment. Now when I am doing startActivityForResult and launch camera. When come back from camera calling fragment get remove and previous fragment comes up.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            File photo = Utils.getImagePath();
            clickImagePath = photo.getPath();
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photo));
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
```

Above code is using to call Camera Intent, now come back from camera, this fragment removed already and parent activity popup last fragment from backstack.
Please suggest.

Comment: show your onActivityResult method. and also how you add the fragment, are you add, or replace?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

into your Activity component in `manifest.xml` as some of the camera application makes the origin activity(the activity who fires `CAMERA` intent) to lose their states.